# radio_button_tag value changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Using Rails 3.2.0.rc2 and ruby 1.9.3p0

In app/views/requests/_form.html.erb I have the following code for showing radio buttons to set the value of :req_driverage (@requests.req_driverage) (in the database, table requests has column req_driverage of type integer):

```
<%= f.label "Authorized age:" %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:req_driverage, "0") %>
<%= label_tag(:req_driverage_0, "Any driver aged 21 years and over") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:req_driverage, "1") %>
<%= label_tag(:req_driverage_1, "Any driver aged 25 years and over") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:req_driverage, "2") %>
<%= label_tag(:req_driverage_2, "Any driver aged 30 years and over") %>
```

Before sending this through actionmailer, I am viewing the value of @request.req_driverage in the log file:

```
logger.info("Value is #{@request.req_driverage}")
```

However, this is only showing "Value is ", meaning that the value is nil (undefined?), even though it has been selected before creating the object.

The strange thing is that I am seeing

```
"req_driverage"=>"1",
```

(if radio button option two was selected) in the browser, when I comment out the call to `mail` in the actionmailer file and get the error `A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message`.

Can anyone please guide me on what is wrong with the above erb code? Or point me to where the value of req_driverage is being changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.label "Authorized age:" %>
<%= f.radio_button(:req_driverage, "0") %>
# and so on ...
```

The form field helper (radio_button in your case) for model attribute must be called **on** the form builder object **f** in order to be properly included in the `params` hash.

Check the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).